# How to handle Upload Key

Tags: android, apk, sign

I have created an apk signed or unsigned and tried to upload it to a release configuration in google android developer. I get always back that the apk has an invalid signature.
When creating the release configuration google tells me that it has created an certificate with private key, but I can download only the certificate. So it does not help me signing an apk.
I did not find a way to upload my key to google as upload key.
What I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

There is a [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing) how to sign your app properly. Follow this steps and you will be fine. You will find, what you are doing wrong. This is a really extensive documentation.

**When to upload the `Certificate` of the `public Key`:**

The following describes the situations in which you see the option to register an upload certificate in the Play Console:

> When you publish a new app that’s signed with a signing key and opt it
> in to Play App Signing.
>
> When you are about to publish an existing app that’s already opted in
> to Play App Signing, but it is signed using its signing key.

**How:**

Now that you have your upload certificate, register it with Google when prompted in the Play Console. [More information](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?visit_id=637537500846068501-3427255756&rd=1#Upgrade)

**Important Note:** Check the following two boxes to pass your apk through Google otherwise it will be reject!

[image: Check lower 2 boxes]

**Upload Key:**

The key you use to sign the app bundle or APK before you upload it for app signing with Google Play. You must keep the upload key **secret**. However, you can share the `certificate` that is generated using your `upload key`. You may generate an `upload key` in one of the following ways:

> If you choose for Google to generate the app signing key for you when
> you opt in, then the key you use to sign your app for release is
> designated as your upload key.
>
> If you provide the app signing key to Google when opting in your new
> or existing app, then you have the option to generate a new upload key
> during or after opting in for increased security.
>
> If you do not generate a new upload key, you continue to use your app
> signing key as your upload key to sign each release.

**Creating Signed APK**

> **Step 1:** Go to `Build`>`Generate Signed APK`>`Next` (module selected would
> be your module , most often called "app")
>
> **Step 2:** Click on create new
>
> **Step 3:** Basically, fill in the form with the required details. The
> confusing bit it is where it asks for a Key Store Path. Click on the
> icon on the right with the 3 dots ("..."), which will open up a
> navigator window asking you to navigate and select a `.jks` file.
> Navigate to a folder where you want your keystore file saved and then
> at the File Name box at the bottom of that window, simply enter a name
> of your liking and the OK button will be clickable now. What is
> happening is that the window isnt really asking you chose a `.jks` file
> but rather it wants you to give it the location and name that you want
> it to have.
>
> **Step 4:** Click on Next and then select Release and Voila ! You are done.

**How to upload:**

> How to upload to [Google Console](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/upload-bundle).
>
> How to [Opt in new app](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#enroll_new).

Comment: From this tutorial I am coming
I get through it until it is noted how to create an upload key. There it is specified that I will be asked for the upload certificate during creating the release. But when I upload the signed apk or bundle, I get an error that the certificate is unknown. 
How and when can I upload the certificate of the upload key?

Comment: I edit my answer. That will help you to understand your mentioned "when" and "how". :)

Comment: Still the same problem:
Today for new apps Google does not allow to generate the signing key for the app. Google only allows to specify a upload key and I have somehow to submit the certificate to Google. But How? When I create a new release there text at the top about keys is only informational, no upload possible.

"!If you choose for Google to generate the app signing key for you when you opt in, then the key you use to sign your app for release is designated as your upload key.!"

So this is the only way left, but I have to load the public key to Google and cannot find the way how,

Comment: I think I got, why your apk will be reject. Take a look at the "Important Note" Section in my answer. If you generate the signed apk it must be ticked.

Comment: Was it successful?

Comment: I found something about a PEPK-Download tool. But it is outdated as you cannot upload keys for app-signing any more. When you follow where to download it you find a menu entry "Release Management => App Signing". But today you find only "App Bundle Explorer". Following this link you can read some infos and then you are forwarded to the same page you did come from.

Comment: I get your point. I made a little tutorial at the end of my answer. Please try that again. Maybe it will go then. Repeat till it works, but carefully. Probably you are doing a tiny mistake with huge impact.

Comment: What you added I know. It is how to sign the apk in the Android Studio. It works fine and it even generates on the way a file containing the public key (pem format) for uploading. But I have to upload the the public key (or certificate) of the private key used at this moment to Google. And exactly this is the problem.

Comment: Okey. Got that. Check the end of my answer. I found 2 interesting links. First is what you was searching for. And 2nd ist to opt a new app. This documentation is really nested...